# How to calculate cosine similarity between vector and each rows of data frame in R?

Tags: r, cosine-similarity

this is my dataframe a:

```
                    ui 194635691 194153563 177382028 177382031 195129144 196972549 196258704 194907960 196950156 194139014 153444738
1 56320e0e55e89c3e14e26d3d      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01     0.000         0         0
2 563734c3b65dd40e340eaa56      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0
3 563e12657d4c410c5832579c      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0
4 565181854c24b410e4891e11      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0
5 5651b53fec231f1df8482d23      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.027         0         0
6 56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb8f      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0
7 56549946735e782a885957e6      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.08      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0
8 56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a37      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0
9 5654a35a735e782a8859a053      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00     0.000         0         0
```

What I want to do here is calculate the cosine similarity between  useridvector
and each row of data frame a but without first column(ui)
I have tried following code so far:

```
  user_id=actions_slippers$ui[i]#user_id is coming from another dataframe called action_slippers
  useridvector=a[a$ui %in% user_id, ]
  p=as.vector(cosine(t(a[,2:ncol(a)]))[,1])# this measures cosine similarity between first row of dataframe a and each other of rows from dataframe a
```

but I want to calculate cosine similarity between useridvector and each row of dataframe a without first column.
useridvector looks like this:

```
 ui 194635691 194153563 177382028 177382031 195129144 196972549 196258704 194907960 196950156 194139014 153444738
 5651b53fec231f1df8482d23         0         0         0         0         0        0         0         0     0.027         0         0
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Hmm what about `1-skmeans::skmeans_xdist(as.matrix(df[, -1]))` or `lsa::cosine(t(as.matrix(df[, -1])))`? Several R packages have cosine (dis)similarity measures. You can exclude the 1st col by using `df[, -1]`, assuming your data is in `df`.

Comment: @ lukeA,Are your codes calculate cosine similarity between useridvector and  dataframe?

Answer (score 5):

`cosine{lsa}` works. I'd like to share my try.

suppose you save the data in a `dataframe` like:

```
> data
                        ui X194635691 X194153563 X177382028 X177382031 X195129144 X196972549 X196258704 X194907960 X196950156 X194139014 X153444738
1 56320e0e55e89c3e14e26d3d       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.01      0.000          0          0
2 563734c3b65dd40e340eaa56       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00      0.000          0          0
3 563e12657d4c410c5832579c       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00      0.000          0          0
4 565181854c24b410e4891e11       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00      0.000          0          0
5 5651b53fec231f1df8482d23       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00      0.027          0          0
6 56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb8f       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00      0.000          0          0
7 56549946735e782a885957e6       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.08       0.00       0.00       0.00      0.000          0          0
8 56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a37       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00      0.000          0          0
9 5654a35a735e782a8859a053       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.00      0.000          0          0
```

Using `data[,-1]` or `subset.data.frame(data, select = names(data)[-1]` to eliminate the first column,then convert to matrix and use the `cosine{lsa}`

```
> res <- lsa::cosine(t(as.matrix(data[, -1])))
> res
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

PS: install the `lsa` package and see `?cosine` for detail info

============================ update =====

The resulting matrix is like,

```
      user1 **user2** user3 **user4**
user1   1    0 
user2        1
user3    ...       1
user4
```

where element(i,j) means the similarity between user i and user j.
and if your `userid` has 2 users say user 2 and user 4.
Then you want to find the similarity between these 2 users to other users.
which is a sub matrix of the entire similarity matrix.
Then use res[, c(2,4)] to obtain the desired matrix.

Comment: @ Dylan, thanks for your answer.but I want to calculate cosine similarity between useridvector (as you can see at above my question) and dataframe.ı want to get result as a vector and this vector should be like first element is a csoine similarity between useridvector and first row of dataframe second element should be is a cosine similarity between useridvector and second row of dataframe and its goes on.... actually my useridvector is 5.rows of dataframe but its coming from another dataframe.if you explain me this,would be great.many thanks in advance

Comment: @ Dylan, I just edited my question.You can see useridvector what looks like.I think my question is more clear now

Comment: @OzgurAlptekın,  the answer is same. If you want do it step by step, use 2 `for` loop